# CodeIgniter 4, Dompdf & Twig

Tags: codeigniter, twig, dompdf, codeigniter-4

I am using Twig with my CodeIgniter 4 project. I need to generate pdf reports and I am providing the HTML via Twig. The problem I am facing is that dompdf is not getting the stylesheets included in the Twig file.

When I do

`return $this->response->setBody($this->twig->render('customers/quotation_request.html.twig'));`

the HTML appears with the correct styling on the browser; so I know there is no problem in the way I included the stylesheets.

I included the stylesheets as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Bootstrap Css -->
    <link href="{{ 'css/bootstrap.min.css' | _base_url }}" id="bootstrap-style" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <!-- Icons Css -->
    <link href="{{ 'css/icons.min.css' | _base_url }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
```

Here's my code to generate the PDFs:

```
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->getOptions()->setChroot(ROOTPATH . 'public');
$dompdf->loadHtml($this->twig->render('customers/quotation_request.html.twig'));
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream();
```

As per dompdf's documentation you need to set `$dompdf->getOptions()->setChroot(-->public folder location here<--);` to the project's `public` folder so that dompdf get access to it but that code doesn't seem to work. The PDFs are being generated without any styling.

Comment: include the css inline

Answer (score 0):

Use inline CSS i.e inside a tag
`<a style="color:red">hello</a>`
or
Use Style tags

```
a{
 color:red;
}
</style>
```

DOMPDF doesn't support links to css files. You can check it in official docs of DOMPDF